# Access a JavaFX TextArea within Tab returned from a TabPane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I would like to access a text area placed within a Tab. All the Tabs in the TabPane will have a TextArea. Unfortunately Tab is not an interface and there does not seem a way to change the type held inside of the TabPane so I can not see a way to make code know that there is going to be a TextArea inside of the generic tab without keeping a separate list of them somewhere outside. TabPane can only return a Tab and tab does not distinguish that it holds a TextArea and even if I make an extension of Tab and give it to the TabPane it will still only return a Tab. Keeping an outside list seems really hacky and I dont think that would ever be the intended design. So what am I missing here. I am not using FXML.

Comment: You can of course ***cast*** the content of a `Tab`. A more direct way than looking for it in this node is probably more hacky than storing the `TextArea`s in a proper data structure...

Comment: Show how you intend to use the code. We can't recommend a design without knowing how it will be used.

Answer (score -1):

You could create your own extension of a `Tab` whose content is a `TextArea` and provide a `getTextArea()` method for it.

That way, you can know each `Tab` will have a `TextArea` and you can manipulate it however you would like.

Below is a simple application to demonstrate:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple UI
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Create the TabPane
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        // Create some TextAreaTabs to put into the TabPane
        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(
                new TextAreaTab("Tab 1", "This is tab 1!"),
                new TextAreaTab("Tab 2", "This is tab 2!"),
                new TextAreaTab("Tab 3", "This is tab 3!")
        );

        // A button to get the text from each tab
        Button button = new Button("Print Text");

        // Set the action for the button to loop through all the tabs in the TabPane and print the contents of its TextArea
        button.setOnAction(e -> {
            for (Tab tab : tabPane.getTabs()) {

                // You'll need to cast the Tab to a TextAreaTab in order to access the getTextArea() method
                System.out.println(tab.getText() + ": " +
                        ((TextAreaTab) tab).getTextArea().getText());
            }
        });

        // Add the TabPane and button to the root layout
        root.getChildren().addAll(tabPane, button);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
// This is the custom Tab that allows you to set its content to a TextArea
class TextAreaTab extends Tab {

    private TextArea textArea = new TextArea();

    public TextAreaTab(String tabTitle, String textAreaContent) {

        // Create the tab with the title provided
        super(tabTitle);

        // Set the Tab to be unclosable
        setClosable(false);

        // Set the text for the TextArea
        textArea.setText(textAreaContent);

        // Set the TextArea as the content of this tab
        setContent(textArea);

    }

    public TextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }
}
```

---

A simpler option would be to simply cast the `getContent()` method for each `Tab` to a `TextArea` within your loop:

```
((Text Area) tab.getContent()).getText()
```

I find the first option to be more readable and flexible as you can configure all your tabs to be identical within one location.

Comment: @kleopatra - I updated my answer to include a simpler alternative. But without knowing the amount of customization the OP would need for each Tab, I still find my first method to be preferable, personally.

Comment: if we don't know any details (like f.i. the amount of customization) we should assume there are none and stick to basic best-practices, shouldn't we :) Which here is very clear: favour configuration over inheritance.